# Android: onCreate not running in a FragmentActivity when its corresponding XML is inflated?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

New to Android development, and am trying to run an instance of the Google Maps activity inside a tab.

I currently have this set up via a ViewPager/TabLayout, using a custom Fragment pager class that stores a Fragment for each tab, with each respective Fragment inflating the XML file for the Activity I want them to contain in their onCreateView method. The code looks like this:

```
// Inside main activity onCreate
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
viewPager.setAdapter(new MainFragmentPager(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this));

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

..

```
// Fragment pager class
...
private Fragment pageFragments[] = new Fragment[] {
        MapsPageFragment.newInstance(),
        DetailsPageFragment.newInstance()
};

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return pageFragments[position];
}
...
```

and

```
// Inside each fragment class
...
public static MapsPageFragment newInstance() {
    MapsPageFragment fragment = new MapsPageFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);

    return view;
}
...
```

with activity_maps being the pre-generated Google Maps activity XML:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="org.<name>.MapsActivity" />
```

and MapsActivity being the FragmentActivity associated with this.

The issue I am seeming to have is as follows:

- When inflated, the context for the view produced from activity_maps isn't the one specified in the XML file (the one that should be controlling it), but the main activity.
- Thus, none of the methods i.e. onCreate in MapsActivity are ever run.

How do I set this up so that the context is set properly? I need the Google Maps FragmentActivity to be the one controlling this Fragment's View, not the one from the class controlling the TabLayout/ViewPager (the main activity).